# How to remove <p> tag from the entire javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, testimonials

I have a weird issue with the plugin, [Indeed My Testimonial](http://demoimtst.wpindeed.com/). I used this plugin at the footer to do a carousel of testimonials. For a specific page at http://urlgone.com/f426b6/, it does not have the carousel, instead all are listed one after another.

It doesn't happen to all other pages. I am suspecting is the plugin WP-Members (in wordpress.org plugin directory) that caused this error as it is the only difference between this page and the rest.

I believe the error for this is because of the `<p>` tag at the javascript at line 571 for that error page but I have no idea how to remove that.

```
<p><script></p>
<p>                                 jQuery(document).ready(function() {</p>
<p>                                   var owl = jQuery('#indeed_carousel_view_widget_2897');</p>
<p>                                   owl.owlCarousel({</p>
<p>                                            singleItem : true,</p>
<p>                                            items : 1,</p>
<p>                                            itemsDesktop : false,</p>
<p>                                            itemsDesktopSmall : false,</p>
<p>                                            itemsTablet: false,</p>
<p>                                            itemsMobile : false,</p>
<p>                                            transitionStyle : false,</p>
<p>                                            paginationSpeed : 500,</p>
<p>                                            slideSpeed : 500,</p>
<p>                                         navigation : false,</p>
<p>                                         pagination : false,</p>
<p>                                         autoPlay : true,</p>
<p>                                         stopOnHover : true,</p>
<p>                                         responsive : true,</p>
<p>                                         lazyEffect : false,</p>
<p>                                            lazyLoad : false,</p>
<p>                                   });</p>
<p>                                 });         </p>
<p>                               </script></div>
```

I will greatly appreciate your guidance to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Pasted the codes but I don't think it helps.